# How to reach second prefix in xml using posgresSQL

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xpath, xmltable

the problem is that I need to extract data from xml, I know how to extract them, but I can't pass prefixes, maybe you can help

```
   <ns2:PositiveInfo xmlns:ns2="http://ws.nGCR">
                <BatchResponse xmlns="http://katana">
                    <Header>
                        <BatchId>11480644</BatchId>
                        <State>Finished</State>
                        <BeginTimeStamp>2022-09-10T10:21:48Z</BeginTimeStamp>
                        <TimeStamp>2022-09-10T10:21:50Z</TimeStamp>
                        <FinishTimeStamp>2022-09-10T10:21:50Z</FinishTimeStamp>
                        <Duration>2.3571</Duration>
                        <Identifier>600e19f5cc5b4707944b126cc8f6103a</Identifier>
                        <Subscriber>2810192</Subscriber>
    .....
```

Now im in `PositiveInfo` prefix, how to reach `BatchResponse` prefix?

until now I have this query :

```
    select *
from(
select unnest(xpath('/responseContainer/ns2:Report/ns2:Registers/ns2:PositiveInfo',  
       response_body::XML,  
       array[array['ns2','http://ws.nGCR']]))::XML as test
from stage_lt.cb_data_execution_entry_details deed
where  id = 178752351)xx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `BatchResponse` element, whose name is in the `http://katana` namespace, you'll need to bind another prefix (e.g. `katana`) to the namespace URI `http://katana`, just as you have bound the `ns2` prefix to the namespace URI `http://ws.nGCR`, then you can use `katana:` as a namespace prefix in your XPath expression, e.g. `/responseContainer/ns2:Report/ns2:Registers/ns2:PositiveInfo/katana:BatchResponse`

Comment: Can you put example from my query how to put another prefix ?

Comment: In your example, the third parameter to your `xpath` function call appears to be an array of namespace bindings. Try adding a second element to that array, giving the prefix and namespace URI for the katana namespace. I'm guessing something like this `array[array['ns2','http://ws.nGCR'], array['katana','http://katana']]` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

To reach the
BatchResponse
prefix, you need to add the corresponding namespace prefix and URI to your XPath query. Assuming that
BatchResponse
is a child element of
PositiveInfo
, you can modify your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    unnest(xpath('/responseContainer/ns2:Report/ns2:Registers/ns2:PositiveInfo/ns:BatchResponse',
      response_body::XML,
      array[array['ns2','http://ws.nGCR'], array['ns', 'http://katana']])
    )::XML AS test
  FROM stage_lt.cb_data_execution_entry_details deed
  WHERE id = 178752351
) xx
```